# Find the minimum positive integer $r$ for which there exists an $r$-regular graph $G$ such that $\kappa(G) \neq \lambda(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

> Find the minimum positive integer $r$ for which there exists an $r$-regular graph $G$ such that $\kappa(G) \neq \lambda(G)$. Verify your answer.

*(Chartrand, Gary, and Ping Zhang. A First Course in Graph Theory. Mineola, NY: Dover Publications, 2012.)*

I know from a theorem that $\kappa(G) \leq \lambda(G)$ for every graph $G$.

Here is my attempt:
Let $L$ be a minimum-edge-cut for $G$. Then $G-L$ has exactly two components $C_1,C_2$ - only two for otherwise one can find a smaller cut.

Assume now that no two edges in $L$ share an end-vertex (otherwise $\kappa < \lambda$).

$|L|=\lambda(G)$

Furthermore, since $G$ is regular and no two edges in $L$ are incident to a same vertex, both $|C_1|,|C_2| \geq r-1$

$\implies |G|\geq 2(r-1) \implies r \leq 1+\frac{|G|}{2}$. So the opposite of this condition would imply the assumption is not true i.e. $r > 1+\frac{|G|}{2}$. In addition, $r\leq |G|-1$.

[Plotting these two inequalities](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cimaod2kh9) gives $r\geq 4$ for the question.

Is my working correct?

Comment: What you're doing could help you figure out the right $r$, but if you want to show that $r=4$ is the minimum, the way you do that is by (1) showing that $\kappa(G)=\lambda(G)$ for all $3$-regular graphs and (2) showing a specific $4$-regular graph where $\kappa(G) \ne \lambda(G)$.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I was assuming that $\kappa \neq \lambda$ for all $r\geq 4$ - which is not necessarily true.